# In app purchase - Error while retrieving information from server [DF-AA-20]

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, android-inapp-purchase

when I want to make In app purchase in my `APP`, I get this `ERROR`:

[image: iamge]

**What I have tried:**

- alpha and beta
- add tester + opt-in
- check IAP ID
- leaderboards are working, so other google IDs are correct
- reinstall google play and services
- I have full rollout (BETA)

Nothing helped me, what else am I doing wrong?

**Thanks for help guys :)**

//edit:
btw my APP is published, so I do not have suspended account https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afterclap.hubenour

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166302/i-cant-purchase-anything-on-play-google-i-get-error-error-retrieving-informat

Comment: Any solution for this? even my app is published but am still getting this error?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue, I have the same with the exact same circumstances.

Comment: Please post answer here if you did resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491289/android-in-app-billing-subscription-purchase-gives-error-df-aa-20?noredirect=1#comment95788565_54491289